# How to select date for 18 months from the current date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select a date that gives me 18 months from the current date, but I am not getting exactly 18 months.

Before Running the query, min and max dates are.

MIN Date: 02/22/2018

MAX Date: 03/26/2021

Query

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,-548,cast(GETDATE() as datetime));
```

Above query returns the min date as 10/15/2019. So from 10/15/2019 to 03/26/2021 is 17 months and 12 days. While my expectation is to get 10/05/2019 from this query so that I get exactly 18 months or 548 days.

Comment: Why not just use the month in `dateadd`?

Comment: It won't make any difference and I've tried it.

Comment: Why are you using `GETDATE` if you want to go back 18 months from 03/26/2021?

Comment: Then what should I use? is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DATEADD(month,-18,cast(GETDATE() as datetime))`

Comment: This give the same date. I've tried this already.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I wasn't getting a correct date was because the query looks for current date GETDATE() and in the database, I don't have data for the current date due to which I was encountering differences. I exported data from STAGE to DEV environment and now I am getting correct date.